# An exercise on C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

A representation $\pi$: $A\rightarrow B(H)$ is said to be irreducible if $\pi(A)$ has no non-trivial invariant subspace. A C*-algebra $A$ is said to be liminal if $\pi(A)=K(H_{\pi})$ for every irreducible representation $\pi$ of $A$. (Here, $K(H_{\pi})$ denotes all the compact operators in $H_{\pi}$)

Then I meet with an exercise:

**Every commutative C*-algebra is liminal.**

How to prove this question?

Comment: It is a trivial consequence of the fact that every irreducible representation of a commutative $C^*$-algebra is  one-dimensional. So you should probably try to prove the latter instead.

Comment: @julien, could you explain to me more specific?

Comment: @Belle-tiantian, based on Julian's hint, note that any commutative c star algebra is of the form $C(X)$, now the one dimensional irreducible representation is given by any evaluation map, here $H$ is just the complex numbers.

Comment: @julien may be you could organize all these comments into the answer?

Comment: This is corollary 3.11 in [these notes](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~ifarah/Ftp/2005k26-ruiz.pdf) by I. Farah. @Norbert If you feel like writing something up, go ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, every irreducible representation of an abelian C*-algebra is one-dimensional.

Indeed, if $\pi:A\to B(H)$ is irreducible, then $\pi(A)$ is dense in $B(H)$. As $\pi(A)$ is abelian, we obtain that $B(H)$ is abelian; this implies that $\dim H=1$.

Comment: Why is $\pi(A)$ dense in $B(H)$?

Comment: What does "irreducible" mean to you?

Comment: $\pi(A)$ commutes with no nontrivial projections or $\pi(A)$ has no proper closed invariant subspaces. Does this imply that $\pi(A)$ is dense in $B(H)$?

Comment: Yes, by von Neumann's Double Commutant Theorem.